# I need a specific Quartz cron expression

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I need a cron expression that will fire every second day excluding weekends. 
Example:
The schedule starts on Monday. The schedule continues in the following manner:

- (1st week) Monday>Wednesday>Friday
- (2nd week) Tuesday>Thursday
- (3rd week) Monday>Wednesday>Friday
- (4th week) Tuesday>Thursday

Is that possible using only cron? I know a solution would be to run it every day and when it runs on weekend 'manually' prevent it from running.

Comment: I meant "every second day", not "every second". Like Monday, Wednesday, Friday, skipping Tuesday etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like could help...

```
* * 1-31/2 * mon-fri command.sh
```

That means, "At every minute on every 2nd day-of-month from 1 through 31 and on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday."

https://crontab.guru/#*_*_1-31/2_*_mon-fri

http://corntab.com/?c=*_*_1-31/2_*_MON-FRI

(Didn't tried on real machine)

Comment: Unfortunatelly http://www.cronmaker.com/  says that is incorrect. I guess you cannot set both 1-31/2 and mon-fri. One of them should be '?'.

Comment: Hello, cronmaker.com uses  Quartz cron format (I don't know what is it). My answer for normal posix. Do you need Quartz?

Comment: Exactly, I am using Quartz :)

Comment: sorry, I haven't used Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

I will consider extended expression format so your query will looks like:

```
S M H  DoM  M     DoW     Y
0 0 10 1-31 * 1#1,3#1,5#1 *
```

This query can be understood as: Repeat at 10:00:00 every day of every month where day of week is (monday, wednesday, friday) and it's first week of month.

You would define such 4 queries (i'm considering that 1 in 1#3 is just monday and 3 is week number in month):

```
1.) 0 0 10 1-31 * 1#1,3#1,5#1 *
2.) 0 0 10 1-31 * 2#2,4#2 *
3.) 0 0 10 1-31 * 1#3,3#3,5#3 *
4.) 0 0 10 1-31 * 2#4,4#4 *
```

which runs the same command. But it won't work becouse of limitations of most of evaluators (as i guess).

If you are familiar with .NET, I made evaluator which handle such expressions correctly, but it's only evaluator so what you only receive are dates when your event should occur. There is no job sheduler integrated with it. [Click](https://github.com/Puchaczov/TQL.CronExpression)